# Spark/Hadoop failes to renew lease goes into safe mode, shutsdown, and then can't connect to server and doesn't start

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

So I've got a cluster on GCP using Dataproc. 1 Master, 2 slaves. My system puts items on a queue every hour using rabbitmq, and the consumer runs a spark job via pyspark for each item on the queue. Note: I've configured it so I can import pyspark into a normal python environment, and use spark from there.

After extended periods of running, not too long really, the system prints that it cannot renew it's lease, and then goes into safe mode as such

```
WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.LeaseRenewer: Failed to renew lease for [DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1938993080_12] for 304 seconds.  Will retry shortly ...  
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException): Cannot renew lease for DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1938993080_12. Name node is in safe mode.
Resources are low on NN. Please add or free up more resources then turn off safe mode manually. NOTE:  If you turn off safe mode before adding resources, the NN will immediately return to safe mode.
```

the system will keep running for a short while, and then eventually shut down:

```
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.renewLease(DFSClient.java:892)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.LeaseRenewer.renew(LeaseRenewer.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.LeaseRenewer.run(LeaseRenewer.java:448)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.LeaseRenewer.access$700(LeaseRenewer.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.LeaseRenewer$1.run(LeaseRenewer.java:304)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/03/15 15:52:46 INFO akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Shutting down remote daemon.
16/03/15 15:52:46 INFO akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
16/03/15 15:52:46 INFO akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remoting shut down.
```

I try to start the service again as such

```
python mq_consumer.py
```

which looks like so

```
import json
import pika
from lex_engine import run_engine as re, db_tools as dbt, credentials as creds

# This file consumes form the rabbit mq queue and runs the jobs it gets from
# the queue in spark. It also sets the lock key, to ensure that multiple jobs
# with the same ID don't start at the same time.
ADDR = creds.RABBITMQ_VARS['address']
CONNECTION = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host=ADDR))
CHANNEL = CONNECTION.channel()
QUEUE = creds.RABBITMQ_VARS['queue']
MSERVER = dbt.get_mongo(creds.MONGO_CREDS)
MONGO_DB = MSERVER[creds.MONGO_DB_VARS['database']]
COLLECTION = MONGO_DB[creds.MONGO_DB_VARS['collection']]


for method_frame, properties, body in CHANNEL.consume(QUEUE):
# This removes the message from the queue
CHANNEL.basic_ack(method_frame.delivery_tag)
json_payload = json.loads(body)
if (json_payload['id'] is not None and
        json_payload['body'] is not None and
        json_payload['title'] is not None):
    lock_key = 'le-' + creds.ENVIRONMENT + '-' + json_payload['id']
    if COLLECTION.find_one({u'_id': lock_key}) is None:
        COLLECTION.insert_one({u'_id': lock_key, u'in_use': 1})
        re.run_engine(json_payload)
        COLLECTION.delete_one({u'_id': lock_key})
```

but then spark/hadoop doesn't start again, printing this:

```
16/03/15 20:29:09 INFO akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
16/03/15 20:29:09 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
16/03/15 20:29:09 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :        [akka.tcp://sparkDriverActorSystem@10.128.0.5:35762]
16/03/15 20:29:10 INFO org.spark-project.jetty.server.Server: jetty-8.y.z-    SNAPSHOT
16/03/15 20:29:10 INFO org.spark-project.jetty.server.AbstractConnector:     Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:4040
16/03/15 20:29:10 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy: Connecting to      ResourceManager at lexe-1-m/10.128.0.5:8032
16/03/15 20:29:11 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to   server: lexe-1-m/10.128.0.5:8032. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is      RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
16/03/15 20:29:12 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: lexe-1-m/10.128.0.5:8032. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
16/03/15 20:29:13 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: lexe-1-m/10.128.0.5:8032. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
16/03/15 20:29:14 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: lexe-1-m/10.128.0.5:8032. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
16/03/15 20:29:15 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: lexe-1-m/10.128.0.5:8032. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
16/03/15 20:29:16 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: lexe-1-m/10.128.0.5:8032. Already tried 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
16/03/15 20:29:17 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: lexe-1-m/10.128.0.5:8032. Already tried 6 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
16/03/15 20:29:18 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: lexe-1-m/10.128.0.5:8032. Already tried 7 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
16/03/15 20:29:19 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: lexe-1-m/10.128.0.5:8032. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
16/03/15 20:29:20 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: lexe-1-m/10.128.0.5:8032. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
```

If I reboot the server (debian), it works again, but only to fall prey to the same issue again after some time. Does anyone know how this can be fixed? I've looked into giving the NameNode more resources, but to my thinking this shouldn't prevent the system from starting back up, right? Anyone have any insight?

Comment: After getting the cluster into this bad state, check for log messages in /var/log/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-namenode-*.log and .out.

Comment: Which version of Spark? Hadoop? Scala? Java? Does this only happen with PySpark? I've get a very similar problem as described here https://www.mail-archive.com/user@spark.apache.org/msg47684.html  Also after what period of time it failes to renew token?